# $x\cdot y = \sqrt2$. What can be said about $x$ and $y$

Tags: problem-solving

Given, $x,y\in\Bbb R$ and $x\cdot y=\sqrt{2}$ .Can $x$ and $y$ be taken as $\sqrt[4]{2}$?

Comment: Yes, they can...but also you can take $\;x=\sqrt2,\,y=1\;$ , or $\;y=-4,\,x=-\frac1{2\sqrt2}\;$ , etc. The only things you can say for sure is that they both are non-zero and both are positive or both are negative.

Comment: The set of all such pairs $(x,y)$ forms an equilateral hyperbola in the usual Cartesian coordinate plane.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a geometric point of view of your problem.

All the points lying on the blue curve is the solution of your equation $xy=\sqrt{2}$

[image]

Comment: Sujit.Very nice!(The blue curve is a hyperbola:))+

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course, but $x=1$ and $y=\sqrt2$ are also valid.

You can take $y=\frac{\sqrt2}{x}$ for all $x\neq0.$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, $x=y= \sqrt[4]{2}$ satisfy the equation $xy= \sqrt{2}$. But there are infinitely many other solutions of the equation $xy= \sqrt{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

$|x+y| \ge 2\sqrt[4]{2}$

and one or both of $x$ and $y$ are irrational.